# SQL - Return A when B is exactly x,y,z

Tags: sql, oracle, select, dataset, where-clause

Consider the following table with column A and B:

```
A | B  
--+--  
1 | A  
1 | B  
1 | C  
2 | A  
2 | B  
3 | A  
3 | C  
4 | B  
4 | C
```

I would like to get the value 2 from column A in case my set is [A,B].

**IN**
`select a from table where b IN ('A','B')`, that will return value 1 and 2.

**Intersect**
`select a from table where b = 'A'

intersect

select a from table where b = 'B'

intersect

select a from table where b = 'C'`, that will return 1 however it will not work if I for instance remove the 'B' criteria and only look for [A,C]. Such a query will return 1 and 3.

Is there a smarter way of using sets with one to many relations, or perhaps another approach I just did not think of? I will be using Oracle btw in case any Oracle specific solution should be available.

> EDIT:
>   Use this for testing: [SQLFiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e6378/3/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" query.  I like to solve these using aggregation and a `having` clause for each condition.  In this case, there are three conditions:  Does a given value for A have a B with a value of 'A'?  For 'B'?  For anything else?

This results in the query:

```
select A
from t
group by A
having sum(case when B = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when B = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when B not in ('A', 'B') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: That was just what I was looking for. Does not get much more simple than that huh :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select A 
from t
group by A
having count(*)=2 and min(B)='A' and Max(B)='B'
```